# Real time location sharing with Android

Tags: android, google-maps, location, real-time

What I need to do is share location from one android device and show it on another device(not necessarily android, even web would be fine). I can think of following solutions as of now.

1. Use GPS to get latitude and longitude from android device and send it to a server after fixed intervals(eg. 5 sec) which will store it in database(Can we use firebase for this purpose instead of writing full server side code from scratch?). The client which needs to show the location can now request data from server every 5 secs and plot the location on google map. My question is, is this approach scalable?
2. Is there some Google API that allows real-time location sharing out of the box? I tried searching for it but couldn't find anything like that. Does something like that exist?

Comment: Given the broad specifications, I'd have to add just using the google map app which supports location sharing but does require knowledge of contacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use [Firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) for sharing the location.
2. No, there is no such thing as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Google Places API for Android.  For example, if you wanted to get a latitude/longitude based on a user inputted address, you could use the Autocomplete service:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

I don't think you will have the scalability issue you imagine, because the strain for finding coordinates would be on a Google server, not yours, as well as the mobile device of your users.  You would only need to worry about storing coordinates in a central database somewhere.

Comment: Ok, so that means that for scaling, I only need to worry about users that send data and those who request it. Google places will be irrelevant as I'm getting the latitude/longitude by GPS itself.

Comment: Google Places isn't _irrelevant_, but the load is on someone else's server, and the phone would be calling that directly.  So you only need to be concerned with users sending you GPS data and also retrieving that data.